# Photoshop-like, embeddable web based image editor?

Tags: javascript, flash, canvas, photoshop, image-editing

> [Online Image Editor - Ajax or Flex / Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841112/online-image-editor-ajax-or-flex-flash)
>
> The above wasn't really the answer
>   that I was looking for.

I'm looking for an online image editor which I can embed into my pages, so users can edit images and submit them.

I'm fine with it being Flash or Canvas/JS, no Silverlight or Java please.

Should have these features, or close to:

1. File upload for image or remote url fetch
2. Layer-based like Photoshop
3. Magic Wand/Pen/Pencil/Brush/etc
4. Text editing
5. Cropping tool

Comment: you can see this site
http://www.3p-publisher.com/index.php/id-3p-online-photobook-designer-photo-book-editor-print-business.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm. may have found a winner @ http://www.pixlr.com/wiki/developer/api/js-lib

So far it has pretty much all the features I need and then some, in addition they allow you to embed the application.

I'll test this out and see how it goes.

Comment: Wow! That's a cool library and program -- just tried it out.

Comment: That link is broken. I think the new one is : http://www.pixlr.com/developer/api

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [picnik](http://www.picnik.com/)? It may be what you are looking for.

Comment: that looks awesome, I'll try that out as well.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment above, I have a very similar [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815512/tablet-pc-jquery-widget-extension-or-browser-plugin-for-drawing-into-website) running at the moment. There's nothing there yet.

Then, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825958/online-photoshop-via-html-5s-canvas) previous discussion that has two very interesting links.

Comment: Yeah one of the links is dead, the other one looks good except I'm not sure it's shareable though, this should help out with the research I'm doing though, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Wtf? CanvasPaint was up only yesterday. Oh hell. I think it came with the source, did anybody download it?